# Unable to find port forwarding in Tenda D151 router

Tags: router, portforwarding

Cannot find port forwarding option in Tenda D151 router. Checked Advanced settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

download the document from the the following link and go to page 49. It is called port triggering for Tenda routers.

Link to the manual: http://tendacn.com/en/download/detail-1699.html